# Specifying other MusicBrainz entry in `abcde`

Tags: linux, debian, ripping, abcde

`abcde` automatically searches MusicBrainz to find a match for the CD track tags. I've ripped twelve CDs in a row and it works fine, but now I have a CD for which no MusciBrainz data was found. However, I know that that CD is on MusicBrainz and that the data on the website is correct. How can I tell `abcde` to fetch that set of tags from a specified URL? This is the URL: https://musicbrainz.org/release/4f07f060-5485-43a4-b514-62f8e5f7aea0

The reason I'm not tagging the songs manually is because I was given a bunch of CD's by an elderly person who wants me to put them on a USB stick for her car. There are a few CDs which are not originals, and that's what's causing the problem. (They're all "Unknown Album by Unknown Artist".) That would take me a very long time, so I'd rather have it done automatically.

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

Comment: Unlikely, but do the failing CD's have a [CD-TEXT file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32382/435767)? In that case you [could point abcde to it](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/iiptp8/comment/g38b0l6/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) as a fallback.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, the failing CD's don't have CD-TEXT files. They've likely been copied by someone who had little knowledge of anything computer-related. Does there exist some utility which I could use to generate CD-TEXT files from MusicBrainz data (or another working service)?

Comment: I just discovered MusicBrainz Picard. It's a marvel. Would it be appropriate to answer my own question by telling myself to use Picard?

Comment: Definitely! Self answering helps the next person having this issue (or your future self).

Answer (score 0):

Given that the ultimate goal is tagging the songs on the CDs without having to deal with the issue manually and waste a lot of time, use [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/), which is an automatic tagging tool. This must be done *after* the songs are ripped from the CD. The tool is very easy to use, and can tag whole albums in a single click. The documentation can be found [here](https://picard-docs.musicbrainz.org/en/index.html).